# Not able to call function defined in Obj-c in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm trying to use a third-party library written in objective-c in my project written with Swift. I have copied the file into the project and built the bridge file, and is able to reference the class in the library and use the properties. But I'm not able to call the instance function in the library, XCode just complaining `value of type 'EFCircularSlider' has no member 'setInnerMarkingLabels'`. The code is below:

function in the lib:

```
-(void)setInnerMarkingLabels:(NSArray*)innerMarkingLabels
{
    _innerMarkingLabels = innerMarkingLabels;
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints]; // This could affect intrinsic content size
    [self setNeedsDisplay]; // Need to redraw with new label texts
}
```

the way to call in swift:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let hourSliderFrame = CGRectMake(55, 220, 210, 210)
    hourSlider = EFCircularSlider(frame: hourSliderFrame)
    hourSlider.unfilledColor = UIColor(red: 23/255.0, green: 47/255, blue: 70/255, alpha: 1.0)
    let markingLabels = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]
    hourSlider.setInnerMarkingLabels(markingLabels)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to use the property (dot) assignment notation rather than calling the explicit setter

```
hourSlider.innerMarkingLabels = markingLabels
```

PS: where is `hourSlider` initialized? The code as-is will not compile.

The documentation says

> You access properties on Objective-C objects in Swift using dot
>   syntax, using the name of the property without parentheses.

Comment: but in that way the methods been called after the assignment will not be called, workaround could possibly be used but I just want to know if this is a bug in swift-objective-C migration or I used it in a wrong way.

Comment: Is the explicit setter declared in the ObjC .h file? It has to if you want to use it in Swift. And no, the methods after the assignment will be called because the dot notation calls the explicit setter anyway

Comment: previously there was no function declaration in .h file, I added it and tried but no luck. I found the problem to be weird cause some of the function can be called but some cannot.

Comment: Add a `print` line in the explicit setter to prove that the method is called when using dot notation.

Comment: thanks, looks like it's working. Just one question, is this a bug in Objective-c to Swift migration?

Comment: Of course It's working ;-). I guess it's not a bug but just a terminology convention to use always dot notation.